# How does openmpi -host works

Tags: mpi, openmpi

I wanted to profile an MPI program and read the following code from pgprof manual.

```
mpirun -np 2 -host c0-0,c0-1 pgprof -o output.%h.%p.%q{OMPI_COMM_WORLD_RANK} a.out
```

I couldn't understand the command -host c0-0,c0-1. I checked the openMPI manual get the following.

```
-H, -host, --host <host1,host2,...,hostN>
    List of hosts on which to invoke processes.
```

Ok, so the question comes down what does c0-0, c0-1 come from. I suppose it means hosts, but where does it come from and what does it mean to set it to c0-0, c0-1?

Comment: `--host` accepts the names of the hosts where MPI ranks are to be launched. `c0-0` and `c0-1` are just host names, perhaps following some naming convention known only to whomever has configured the system used by the authors of the manual. One can only speculate about the origin. Could be chassis and board number. Or cluster and node number. Who knows? Would it be less confusing to you if those were named `foo` and `bar`, or simply `host1` and `host2`, instead?

Comment: Hi, @HristoIliev. Thanks for your comment. My doubt is if I'm profiling my own program on a cluster. How could I get know these hosts names?

Comment: if your cluster is correctly installed, just use `mpirun` without the `-host` option is your job script, and simply submit it.

Comment: Hi, @GillesGouaillardet, thank you. I submitted without --host since I didn't know what to put and it works. Do you know at what circumstances this option became useful and how to use it with the proper naming?

Comment: This is useful if you are not running a resource manager, or if you want to do tricky stuff. "proper naming" is site specific since I do not know on which hosts you want to run your app.

Comment: It pays off to read the manual page of the `mpiexec` command. It explains quite a bit about how and where MPI ranks are launched and where the list of hosts comes from.